# No squid and DNS Install

Tags: linux, ubuntu

On my local machine i got this error:

> While trying to retrieve the URL: http://example.com/
>
> The following error was encountered:
>
> Unable to determine IP address from host name for example.com
>   The dnsserver returned:
>
> Name Error: The domain name does not exist. This means that:
>
> The cache was not able to resolve the hostname presented in the URL. 
>   Check if the address is correct.  Your cache administrator is
>   webmaster.

I do not have any DNS server and SQUID install.

Answer (score 0):

Your ISP probably has a transparent proxy, as many of them do. There can be a statusline underneath this error page, something in lines of `Squid at <ip>`, which might give you a clue as to where this cache resides.

Comment: I copy paste whole error message there is not statusline as i mentioned squid is not installed i am using virtual hosting of apache i clear all ips from resolv.conf but no use

Answer (score 0):

It's not your side issue. probably reasons for this:

1. It's a bad domain name, no IP bind to it. (I can't access this site either, so could you double check the name)
2. Your ISP is facing some DNS issue. just report it if your friend can access the site.
3. You changed your DNS setting mistakenly. (since you said it only occurs when you trying to access this site, I think this is not the case)

EDIT: I looked up the domain you provide at some DNS lookup tools, like [DNS Watch](http://www.dnswatch.info/), no result. probably the domain issue

Comment: Its not a domain bind to DNS or my isp ip. its a virtualhost on my local machine it can be any example.com etc